# tail using Grep: Filter certain no. of lines from the log file when ever there is a match on the grep

Tags: grep, tail

Lets say, i want to grep a log file using a string "xyz" like below.

tail -f filename | grep -vw "xyz"

In this case "xyz" is the keyword that i am searching for. And this will filter the lines from the log file which have the words matching "xyz".

I would also like to filter out the next 10 lines from the log file when ever a line matches in the log file for the keyword "xyz". How can i achieve that?

Please help!

Comment: I don't think grep can do this on its own. When you say "filter out the next 10 lines", do you mean "ignore the next 10 lines even if they match 'xyz'"?

Comment: yes, ignore the next 10 lines.

Comment: I think you'll need to use something like `sed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed to achieve this.

```
sed -e '/xyz/,+10d' filename
```

Comment: looks like this command is parsing the entire log file. I don't want to parse the entire log. I would like to only look at the new messages that are being logged now. How can i do that?

Comment: Pipe it with a tail. tail -f  | sed -e '/xyz/,+10d'

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way by using `awk`:

```
tail -f filename | awk 'BEGIN{skip=-1}/xyz/{skip=NR+10}NR>skip{print}'
```